# Data type for Dummy Variables

Tags: python, types, scikit-learn, random-forest, dummy-variable

I am running random forest, support vector machine, and decision tree algorithms for my model. The model contains dummy variables. My question is if there is a rule in Python (scikit-learn) for having a certain data type for dummy variables?

Some of my dummy variables have the data type as int64, uint8 and object.

If I leave some in object form then it seems to improve my model by a lot. Please let me know what is the correct format for dummy variables and if all of them need to be in that format.

I am quite new to Python and machine learning so please explain as clearly as possible.

Thank you.

Edited: Also please let me know if they should be Boolean data type. I am just trying to figure out what is the best approach.

Comment: It's very surprising to me that there would be any difference. Can you provide a MRE?

Comment: @Ben Reiniger sorry I am not familiar with the linguo, what is MRE and how do I get it?

As of now, I have just decided to change the form for all of them into int64. The results aren't great but at least its standard and it is also the format we get when we change the variables via one hot encoding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example